# How do I style this element?

Tags: html, css

How do I access the style `<li>` elements so I can set their property to - `list-style: none;`?

```
<div class="dataTables_paginate paging_bootstrap pagination">
   <ul>
       <li class="prev disabled"><a href="#">? Previous</a></li>
       <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
       <li class="next"><a href="#">Next ? </a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Im looking only to style those LI elements specifically not all LI elements globally

Comment: Read [ask] first. `:)` See my edit and understand how to write future questions.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.dataTables_paginate ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.dataTables_paginate li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dataTables_paginate paging_bootstrap pagination">
  <ul>
    <li class="prev disabled"><a href="#">? Previous</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="next"><a href="#">Next ? </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `ul` selector to remove the list styling.

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

To change just one set of `ul`give the give your `ul` a class or ID.